# Equivalent of intents in Android for Win 7.*

Tags: android-intent, windows-mobile

Like there are intents in Android, is there any similar functionality in WIN mobile 7.1?

I want to replace the stock address book with my own. Replace as in, whenever user clicks the contact from the stock address book it should open my application address book.

Answer (score 1):

No, Windows Phone does not allow this type of capability override.